# Best practice for a dashboard

Tags: ember.js

I'm writing an app using RoR for the back-end and Ember.js for the front-end.

The app structure is as follows:

- Multiple Projects
- Each Project has Tasks and Milestones

The UI structure is as follows:

- Two-column layout, with Projects on the left sidebar
- When a Project is selected, there are options for the Tasks and Milestones
- The "main screen" right after someone logs in will be a dashboard. No Project will be selected. The dashboard will contain basic info (upcoming milestones, task progress, etc.)

This all seems pretty normal, but I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement the dashboard.

In RoR without Ember.js, I would probably create a separate dashboard controller. I'm unaware of the best practice for this in Ember.js however.

What is the best way to accomplish this with Ember?

Answer (score 2):

As an introduction, have a look at the Strobe's Sproutcore Training Videos on Vimeo, see http://vimeo.com/user7276077/videos.

All tough they are targeted for SproutCore, the concepts of Models, Views and Controllers are valid for Ember.js too. In [Part 4 - The Controller Layer](http://vimeo.com/25409769), the basic structure of an application which has multiple projects and tasks is stated.

I know that this is not a specific answer to your question, but it should lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this gist by Yehuda Katz](https://gist.github.com/2728699#comments). It talks about the new Router implementation in Ember.js, there are also examples of how to implement nested views etc. The basic approach to use going forward seems to be to:

- Use the router to initialize controllers and assign the correct views.
- Use container views in main sections and then switch out the currentView attribute depending on the state of the application.
- Reduce the use of Singletons
- Allow views to be reused by removing the dependency on Singleton controllers

This seems to be a good way to go about creating larger apps. For your case I would bind containerViews to each of the 2 columns and also a container view to the entire page as a whole. Then manipulate it in the Router depending on the state of the application

Answer (score 0):

The UI structure is as follows:

Two-column layout, with Projects on the left sidebar

When a Project is selected, there are options for the Tasks and Milestones

The "main screen" right after someone logs in will be a dashboard. No Project will be selected. The dashboard will contain basic info (upcoming milestones, task progress, etc.)

This all seems pretty normal, but I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement the dashboard.

In RoR without Ember.js, I would probably create a separate dashboard controller. I'm unaware of the best practice for this in Ember.js however.
ember.js
share|improve this question